# How to minimize amount of requests for Google API (places) autocomplete?

Tags: android, google-api, google-places-api

I am using google API - places to autocomplete locations in `AutoCompleteTextView`. I did couple of tests maybe 20 searches and in my profile on google devs, it's written that I have made 200 API requests.

I understand that it is making request every time I type something or edit typed text. But is there any way how to reduce amount of calls to server?

One of ideas is to define threshold to 3 characters.

Comment: That would be pretty frustrating for a user. If you're concerned about your usage limits (at your ratio, 100,000 requests is still 10,000 searches), you might consider *waiting* maybe 0.75 seconds after the last key press to ping Places. That would reduce the number of calls.  Post your implementation so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: I think your idea with waiting time is the answer actually. If you have anything else, just post it as answer, I will mark it as right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better implementation to reduce the number of calls to the Places API would be to put in a delay of maybe 0.75 seconds after the last key-press.  That would avoid confusion on the part of a user who after seeing autocomplete after 3 letters, sits and waits after typing his 5th.

Comment: it seems the only option you can pass is `offset`, which is based on the number of characters not time.

Comment: @StevenAguilar you don't pass time as a parameter. You programatically wait 0.75 seconds before sending a Places request.  However it's been 4 years - very possible the Places API has changed since then to add additional options/guardrails.

Comment: @Scott How to put that delay?

Answer (score 2):

If you did not find a better solutions( I know it is very late, but I am doing something similar and I found my self in here.)

I think you can "cache" previous results, put them in ArrayList. And then in your adapter when performFiltering is called, start by checking the results you have in your Arraylist and if you receive a number of similar items, dont make a request to the API. I am not sure if it is clear but you can at least save a couple requests like that and for the user side, the autocomplete is always refreshing.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I have already solved it somehow, can't recall how. But yes good point, thank you :)

Comment: It is mentioned in the Google Terms, that `d. No Cache or Storae`.