# Decrease amount of Google Places autocomplete requests

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

Since [June 22, 2016](https://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.be/2016/06/building-for-scale-updates-to-google.html), the Google Maps Javascript API requires a key (again). This means they're tracking your usage. When you use the Google Places API in an [AutoComplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete) textbox, a request is made *for every character you type* meaning that if you search in such a textbox for a city that contains 10 characters, you consumed 10 requests for that day.

I want to lower the amount of requests by setting a time-out before updating the autocomplete popup (like: "wait 750ms before triggering the request"), but I can't find a way to do it.

Is there a way to lower the amount of requests used by the Google Places Javascript API Autocomplete component?

**Edit**: *I am aware of [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27916517) but that handles the Android API, I'm using the JavaScript API*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to minimize amount of requests for Google API (places) autocomplete?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27916517/how-to-minimize-amount-of-requests-for-google-api-places-autocomplete)

Comment: Not in my opinion. I read that article but it is about the Android API

Comment: Ah, thanks - I missed that distinction.

Comment: OP, did you ever find a solution? I ran into the very same problem, and have already wasted two days trying to hack it out of the way

Comment: Nope. I gave up after these two days. Since this happens all in Google JavaScript it's hard to hack. We added a billing account and increased the number of API calls this way. Last month we had too many calls for the first time and were billed 13cents so that's cheaper than these two days of trying 

Comment: Hi there! So do you recommend me dont worry about it? Im having the same problem. Too many calls and its just me that Im using making tests. In two weeks it went over $150

Comment: Well... In the mean time, our bills are close to $1000 each month, not only because of these calls but they certainly are quite a big chunk of that bill. Currently, the company wants to keep Google as it is seen as the best provider for geocoding  but we're searching for alternatives...

Answer (score 3):

You can build your own widget using the [AutocompleteService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#place_autocomplete_service) class, and set your own thresholds.

But honestly, I would **hate** an app that takes such a long time to react to my keystrokes. I would initially blame the phone for not reacting to my touches, but likely realize, eventually, that it is just this one app that is slow to react to my keystrokes, and find a replacement app. Consider that.

Comment: Also to be considered is the fact that Google is charging _per character_ sent, at _each request_. Even if those costs are per "credit", it still amounts to a large amount of expenditure, so reducing is a *must*.